# Storyboard and UIReferenceLibraryViewController

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I just started digging into Storyboard programming and i stumble upon a behavior that i don't know how to reproduce.

I'd like to create a simple Vocabulary based on `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`, this class has a designated initializer that takes a string as parameter with the term to look up for:

```
- (id)initWithTerm:(NSString *)term
```

Now i want to create a simple controller (`UIViewController`)  with a Textfield and a Button, pushing that button it performs a segue to the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`... but i can't understand how to initialize the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` with the text from the textfield of the first controller!

I thought to use custom segues but i can't find a way to control the initialization of my controllers...

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I'll write this anyway...

The only way to accomplish this I can think of would be to alloc-init and then display the UIReferenceLibraryViewController from the buttons action. If anyone has a better Idea i would like to hear it (this one doesn't quite seem to good considering UIReferenceLibraryViewController only came in iOS 5.0 and hence together with storyboards).